How do I delete old deployments (versions) in Google Apps Script when I have over 1700 versions that are active or archived?
I have 1748 versions in Google Apps Script including the current version. I am trying to get down to below 200 to get below the 200 maximum coming in June. When I go to Manage Deployments, I see a bunch of versions in Active (versions I don't use anymore) and a bunch of versions in Archived (2 of which I use). I also use the current version.
What am I doing wrong and how to delete more? I'm also considering starting the project over by copying/pasting the current version, but it would be nice to also keep the other 2 versions that I use easily available.
I tried deleting some versions but only 4 of the 1700+ were able to be deleted. I was expecting to be able to delete more versions

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have not yet reviewed the announcement of the change mentioned. I would be surprised if Google required users to do what you are trying to do. Anyway, please bear in mind that Google Apps Script web app / code editor is intended to handle simple project creation/maintenance tasks. For complex / bulk tasks, use the Google Apps Script API. Note there is a command line app to use the API from a local terminal, the name is CLASP.

Check project history, then on the right you'll see all your versions, which you can delete one by one, or click at the very bottom right corner the bulk delete button.

@Wicket I will look into Google Apps Script API when I get computer time in the library tomorrow. Is CLASP available/allowed on library computers? The announcement when I click Deploy > New Deployment says "This project has exceeded the limit of 200 versions. You can delete multiple versions from the Project history page. After June 1, 2024, you will not be able to create new versions in projects with 200 or more versions"

@Nabnub When I try to delete one by one, "You can not delete this version as it is in use by some deployment." I tried in bulk earlier, and that's how I was able to delete the 4 versions I mentioned in my question, but only those 4 were available to be deleted. Message says "This project has 1743 versions out of which 1743 are in use by active deployments. Actively deployed versions are hidden. In order to delete them, they need to be updated first. Manage deployments"

Were you able to solve this @RicardoBarrios? I am seemingly in the same situation - I was able to undeploy all deployments via Clasp, and the Script's Overview page shows only the Head deployment, but when I try to delete/bulk delete via the Project History page, it throws the error you mentioned. So it seems like I'm stuck unable to deploy. I tried to deploy via Clasp and get the same error. Has anyone found a workaround for this? Thanks!

@DustinKerstein you may want to ask in a new question. I won’t be able to take a close look till I have computer access Monday. I figured the answer involved CLASP or Google Apps Script API so I gave the answer that suggested those a check mark. But I never found the solution.

As you want to delete active versions, you should evaluate the implications of archiving hundreds of versions compared to copying the versions you want to keep for a new project or starting a new project from scratch.
For details on how to manually archive a versioned deployment, see Archive a versioned deployment.
To efficiently do this, you might have to learn new things like how to use the Google Apps Script API and CLASP.
Resources

Create and Manage Deployments (Concepts)
Manage deployments (API)


How do you make an active version inactive? How do you make an archived version inactive? I feel like I'm just going to copy the versions I want to keep to a new project, but I want to be able to delete active/archived versions in the new project too or else I'll eventually run into the same problem.

@RicardoBarrios I just edited this answer.

Thanks @Wicket. I was facing the same problem. I followed below steps to delete versions (one by one).  When I get error "You can not delete this version as it is in use by some deployment." , I go to "Deploy" button > "Manage Deployments" > left top panel of active versions > scroll down in that panel to find the version which I can't delete > select that version > right top corner of Deploy window, there is Archive button > Archived > again on Project history > select and delete that version.

According to a recent release note, now there is an option to multiple unused versions at once.

(Generally Available): You can now delete multiple unused versions at the same time from the Project History page. Refer to Delete multiple versions.

From link included in the mentioned release note:

Delete multiple versions at once
To delete multiple versions at the same time, take the following steps:

In your script project, click history Project History.
Click  Bulk delete versions. A dialog shows a list of versions that you can delete. Versions in use by an active deployment aren't included in the list.
Select the versions to delete and click Delete.
In the dialog, click Delete.


Another option is to use the Apps Script API. There is a command line app to use this API, the name is CLASP.

When I try to delete one by one, I get "You can not delete this version as it is in use by some deployment." I tried in bulk earlier, and that's how I was able to delete the 4 versions I mentioned in my question, but only those 4 were available to be deleted. Message says "This project has 1743 versions out of which 1743 are in use by active deployments. Actively deployed versions are hidden. In order to delete them, they need to be updated first. Manage deployments."

As for CLASP, I only have access to a library computer right now and I'm afraid of using the command prompts because I do not know if it is allowed.

I was able to clean up my versions ( code snapshots). I had a project with over 150 versions, which I wanted to clean up ( as far as I was able to find, AppsScript doesn't delete deployment but archive them ). so I ended up creating a script inside of my AppsScript project to clean up older versions. and so after archiving all my old deployments, I was able to delete all related versions.
You do need a Google Cloud project, which has the AppsScript API enabled, and of course you would need to generate credentials from the Google Cloud project.
Because AppsScript ( or any Google API ) needs OAuth2, I used a library that I imported which developed by Google ( and maybe if I am not doing it on the AppsScript it would have been much easier ). By adding this library and setting the scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments, I was able to write a small function that goes through all the deployments and delete them one by one, so I thought I would share it here as I agree with everyone that is nice to clean it up in an easy way.


const SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_API_URL = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<SCRIPT_ID>/deployments"

function cleanupDeployments() {
  const deploymentsList = listDeployments_();
  deploymentsList.forEach((deployment) => {
    const deploymentId = deployment.deploymentId;
    deleteDeployment_(deploymentId)
  })
}

function listDeployments_() {
  var allDeployments = [];
  var nextToken = undefined;
  do {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getStoredAccessToken_()
      },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,

    };
    var url = SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_API_URL;
    if (nextToken) {
      url = SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_API_URL + "?pageToken=" + nextToken;
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const responseJson = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    allDeployments.push(...responseJson.deployments);
    nextToken = responseJson.nextPageToken;
  } while (nextToken)
  return allDeployments;
}

function deleteDeployment_(deploymentId) {
  const options = {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getStoredAccessToken_()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_API_URL + "/" + deploymentId, options);
  console.log("Deployment with id (" + deploymentId + ") has been deleted")
  return response;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var appScriptService = getService_();
  var isAuthorized = appScriptService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    // Gets the authorized account ID from the scope string. Assumes the
    // application is configured to work with single accounts. Has the format
    // "harvest:{ACCOUNT_ID}".
    var scope = request.parameter['scope'];
    var accountId = scope.split(':')[1];
    // Save the account ID in the service's storage.
    service.getStorage().setValue('Harvest-Account-Id', accountId);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

function getStoredAccessToken_() {
  return JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("oauth2.AppScript")).access_token;
}

function getService_() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('AppScript')

    // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

    // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
    .setClientId('')
    .setClientSecret('')

    // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
    // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments')

    // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

    // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
    // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())

    // Requests offline access.
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

    // Consent prompt is required to ensure a refresh token is always
    // returned when requesting offline access.
    .setParam('prompt', 'consent');
}



